# D3 NGX Line Chart appearing to have a height when it shouldn't

Tags: angular, d3.js, ngx-charts

I'm having a strange issue with my `ngx-charts` line chart.

If you take a look at the GIF below, you'll see 2 line charts. The first one has the bug, the second one is fine.

[image]

The values for the first chart total out to be zero., yet the chart appears to have a value at every x-axis point. It should not have that height, it should be flat on the bottom of the chart like the 2nd chart is.

**Values that created 1st chart** (every item in the list has a value of `0`):

```
[{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 12:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 1:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 2:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 3:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 4:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 5:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 6:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 7:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 8:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 9:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 10:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 11:00 AM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 12:00 PM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 1:00 PM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 2:00 PM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 3:00 PM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 4:00 PM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 5:00 PM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 6:00 PM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 7:00 PM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 8:00 PM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 9:00 PM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 10:00 PM"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 18, 11:00 PM"}]
```

**Values that created 2nd chart** (every item in the list except for 2 items have a value of `0`. The other 2 items are what makes the chart line move upward):

```
[{"value":0,"date":"Feb 16"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 17"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 18"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 19"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 20"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 21"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 22"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 23"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 24"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 25"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 26"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 27"},{"value":0,"date":"Feb 28"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 1"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 2"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 3"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 4"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 5"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 6"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 7"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 8"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 9"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 10"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 11"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 12"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 13"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 14"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 15"},{"value":0,"date":"Mar 16"},{"value":200,"date":"Mar 17"},{"value":200,"date":"Mar 18"}]
```

I've looked all over the `ngx-charts` codebase, no answer found when I try modifying a wide array of settings.

**Update:**

[Here is a gist with the raw SVG HTML](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lansana/3842057322ca344f3e3acda7c814420e/raw/f90d3a04c2c3ba59fa66f0b2af800d7f8657f98e/chart.svg).

Comment: Can you give us the url of the code source of the chart ? That would be great

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Do you give an input for `@Input() yScaleMin: number;`? If yes, the code [here](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/master/src/line-chart/line-chart.component.ts#L363) can be affected for the Y-domain. But i'm not sure that I have the right chart code.

Comment: After looking at my code, no, I don't give a value for `yScaleMin`. I just tried setting it to 0, no effect. Tried setting it to anything above 0 (0.00001, 1, etc), and it fills up the entire line chart instead of just half.

Comment: To be sure about the component, you called it with `ngx-charts-line-chart` ?

Comment: Yes. I am using a forked version with some charts that I don't need removed, but I've paired my forked version with the library and everything looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is perhaps, because your y-min equals your y-max (`0`), if you provide a `yScaleMax` when all your data are at `0`, it can works.

Comment: Nice! If I do `[yScaleMax]="1"` it works. I am just curious why that is necessary... seems like something is fishy to me

Comment: When the domain is `[0,0]` or `[3,3]`, D3 will center it. Which seems not idiot.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your expertise. Took me like a week to get the chart looking how it is now with no D3 experience, and was stuck on this bug for a few days. You solve it in 5 minutes! :P

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know a solution to the gradient problem I have, would you? You see how my line chart gradient "fades in" instead of being "drawn in" like the line? It's because I have CSS on the line to animate the `stroke-dashoffset`. I can't find the equivalent for the gradient, I can only make it fade in by animating it's opacity, but I want it to draw in from left to right like the line.

Comment: No sorry. Just like this I don't know.